# Optimizing with an update/select for every record

Tags: php, mysql

This script works but it's running very slow on the updates. The issue is, for every record I select from the source (DB2) database, I have to check to see if that record (under my logic conditions) already exists, and if so, if the new record is with the existing record's expiration window. If so, it updates. If not it inserts. The inserts are super quick, as expected, but because I'm executing the update query within the while loop it is so slow on updating.

Again, I have to check with each record because they occur so often, so I can't just do a bulk select and then use the logic to update, because the select might contain records 1 - 100 and my while loop might contain record 111, while record 110 was the same record which would need to be updated. Does that make sense? So without doing the select at the point of record 111, it would insert it instead of updating because it would be unaware of record 110 since the initial select would only contain up to 100.

The logic here is a bit odd, and there's a reason for that, but again it works. I'm just hoping to optimize the update a bit speed-wise.

```
$detailStatCheck = "
    SELECT 
         ordrnum as order,
         stat as STATUS,
         cust AS customer,
         build AS build,
         matrl AS matrl,
         pattern AS pattern ,
         date AS SHIPDATE,
         qty AS QUANTITY,
         case when p.stores is null then 1 else p.stores end as STORES
    FROM table1 g
    left join table2 p on g.cust = p.cust;
";

try {
    $detailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($detailStatCheck);
    $detailRslt = $detailCheck->execute();
    $count2 = $detailCheck->fetch();
    print_r($count2);
}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

$validCheck = "
        SELECT 
            sku_id,
            customer_id,
            expire_date
        FROM customerplacetest p
            INNER JOIN skus s
                ON p.sku_id = s.id
        WHERE p.customer_id = :customer
            AND   s.build = :build
            AND   s.matrl1 = :matrl
            AND   s.pattern1 = :pattern
            AND   p.expire_date > date_add(convert(:SHIPDATE,date), interval 7 day)
    ";

$updatePlacement = "
        UPDATE customerplacetest d
        inner join skus s
        ON d.sku_id = s.id
        SET expire_date = DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(:SHIPDATE, CHAR(20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),INTERVAL 127 DAY),
            quantity = :QUANTITY
        WHERE d.customer_id = :customer
        AND s.build = :build
        AND s.matrl1 = :matrl
        AND s.pattern1 = :pattern

    ";

$checkExistingValid = $MysqlConn->prepare($validCheck);
$insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($insertPlacement);
$update = $MysqlConn->prepare($updatePlacement);


while ($row2 = $detailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $values = [
            ":customer" => $row2["customer"],
            ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
            ":STORES" => $row2["STORES"],
            ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
            ":order" => $row2["order"],
            ":build" => $row2["build"],
            ":matrl" => $row2["matrl"],
            ":pattern" => $row2["pattern"],
        ];

        $values2 = [
            ":customer" => $row2["customer"],
            ":build" => $row2["build"],
            ":matrl" => $row2["matrl"],
            ":pattern" => $row2["pattern"],
            ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
        ];

        $values3 = [
            ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
            ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
            ":customer" => $row2["customer"],
            ":build" => $row2["build"],
            ":matrl" => $row2["matrl"],
            ":pattern" => $row2["pattern"],
        ];


        try{

            //Array will contain records that are valid
            $existingVldRslt = $checkExistingValid->execute($values2);
            $count4 = $checkExistingValid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            print_r($count4);

            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    echo "QUERY TWO FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }

                if(!empty($count4)){
                    print_r("updating");

                        for($i=0; $i<$row2['QUANTITY']; $i++){
                            try{
                                $updateRslt = $update->execute($values3);
                            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                                echo "UPDATE_FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                }else{
                    print_r("inserting");
                    if($row2["QUANTITY"] >= $row2["STORES"]){
                        for($i=0; $i<$row2["STORES"]; $i++){     
                            try{
                                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                                echo "INSERT_FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }elseif($row2["QUANTITY"] < $row2["STORES"]){
                        for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++){   
                            try{
                                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
                            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                                echo "INSERT_FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
         }
```

Comment: Have you checked through `EXPLAIN` whether the logic part needs any more indices to run faster?

Comment: create a stored procedure and pass the load to the database

Comment: @NicoHaase yes but there's nothing else unique to use. I could do a foreach using order number maybe

Comment: I'm not talking about unique indices. Identify the slow queries and attach them plus the `EXPLAIN` result to the question, maybe the community has an idea?